# repair npm global package symlinks

Tags: node.js, npm, osx-mavericks

Recently upgraded to OSX Mavericks and had all my npm global module symlinks wiped out! Reinstalling npm got npm to work again.

Is there a way to have npm recursively go through /usr/local/lib/node_modules/
and create the symlinks in /usr/local/bin for each package? (yes, it is in my Path)

Is there a way to do this a single package at a time?

My Google-fu is failing me at the moment. I have over 40 packages and I would hate to have to reinstall all of them or manually create symlinks for all the bins!

OSX 10.9
npm 1.4.14
node 0.10.29

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run this to rebuild in place without reinstalling:

```
for i in "$(npm prefix -g)/lib/node_modules/"*; do
  sudo npm build -g "$i"
done
```

But, are you *sure* that the symlinks are broken, and not that it simply changed your `PATH` environment variable or something?  What does `npm bin -g` output?

Comment: I will give this a spin. `npm bin -g // -> /usr/local/bin`

Comment: /usr/local/bin is the first folder in path. And I checked that folder and none of my node simulinks were there. Brew simulinks were also gone, but brew link <package> brought those back and there were only two to link again.

Comment: Sweet! This works! I will have to write this down in my `Things that will save my life` notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Well this way is easy but it will re-download stuff, but it will still probably be faster than trying to script a way to repair them in place without redownloading:

```
npm install -g $(ls /usr/local/lib/node_modules)
```

If you try to manually create the symlinks, you are almost certain to miss some and/or make so mistakes, so I would not recommend that.

Comment: I thought this had worked but it only fixed some of the packages. I am not sure why it did not simulink them all as it seemed to re-install all the packages, but many of the packages are not simulinked and it seems to have broken gulp which I already had working. :(